# How to get values from RecyclerView to detail activity

Tags: java, android, web-services

I have an acitivity to show my data. It contains RecyclerView with CardView. I am getting values from web service. But showing just 2 of them in CardView. When i click to CardView , it is starting new activity for details. And in this activity , i want to fill the components with the values. I need help on this. How can i do this thing ? Should i call web service again with query , or is there any possible ways to do it in Android ?

I tried to make some of variables Static but my mind is confused and i have no idea about how to do this thing. Btw , if i am in wrong topic please redirect me to the valid one.

Here is the code that i am getting values from Web Service

```
  public void CallService(){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://10.0.3.2:45455/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    JsonPlaceholderAPI jsonPlaceholderAPI = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceholderAPI.class);

    Call<List<Records>> call = jsonPlaceholderAPI.records();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Records>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Records>> call, Response<List<Records>> response) {
            if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                Log.v("CODE : " , String.valueOf(response.code()));
                return;
            }
            InitData(response.body());
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Records>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.v("ERROR :  " , t.getMessage());
          }
    });
```

Here is the InitData For pass values to RecyclerView.

```
public void InitData(List<Records> body){
    List<Records> record;
    record = body;
    for(Records records : record) {
        arrayList.add(new RecyclerLayout(" KODU : " + records.getKODU() , "AÇIKLAMA : " + records.getACIKLAMA()));
        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(arrayList);
    }
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Here is the redirecting to detail activity code

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder , final int position) {
    holder.kod.setText(arrayList.get(position).getKodu());
    holder.aciklama.setText(arrayList.get(position).getAciklama());
    holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = holder.view.getContext();
         //   System.out.println("CLICKED " +position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, KayitDetay.class);

            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Here is my POJO Without Getters and Setters(They're in it but just i'm not pasting it here)

```
 @SerializedName("KODU")
@Expose
private String kODU;
@SerializedName("ACIKLAMA")
@Expose
private String aCIKLAMA;
@SerializedName("KAPALI_FL")
@Expose
private boolean kAPALIFL;
@SerializedName("TARIH")
@Expose
private String tARIH;
@SerializedName("TUTAR")
@Expose
private double tUTAR;
@SerializedName("DURUM")
@Expose
private int dURUM;
```

I want to see my values on another activity.

Comment: Pass your model class with the click method of interface(callback) in the `putExtra` method of Intent.

Comment: Ah. I forgot add  my OnClick redirect.

Comment: Yes make an interface, and pass the object in adapter class and perform click from view holder, get the model of that particular position and pass it over intent.

Comment: you can simply pass your data using Intent putExtra

Comment: To be honest , i am new on Android. So i don't exactly know how to do it @stutikasliwal .

Comment: Your click is working properly? Is it navigating to another screen?

Comment: @miteshmakwana in my adapter class ?

Comment: @stutikasliwal it is navigating just detail activity. And detail activity is only  reachable from this activity. My detail activity's name is "KayitDetay" . And yes it is working. It is navigating to this activity.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the value using Intent form adapter to activity.

`Intent intent = new Intent(context, KayitDetay.class);
intent.putEXtra("Key",arrayList.get(position).getAciklama())
context.startActivity(intent);`

You can retrieve these value in KayitDetay Activity using the following code : 
//to get a single string 
String value = intent.getStringEXtra("Key")

Comment: So , i don't have to do this calling new intent thing in Activity right ?

Comment: you need to call getIntent in your KayitDetay activity to get the data .

Comment: and you need not have to call new Intent .

Comment: Yeah i know it. I am doing the call new intent thing in my RecyclerViewAdapter class. So it has to stay there. Right?

Comment: yeah. keep new intent in adapter only.

Comment: But there is another question that confusing my mind. I have 6 parameters that returns from Web Service. And i am just showing 2 of them in RecyclerView. But in detail , I want to show all of them. Is this model helps me with it ?

Comment: Yes, you can send the entire object i.e. your data class using peaceable or you send each parameter individually.

Comment: For Parceable Please use  :  intent.putExtra("Key, arrayList.get(position)) and when to retrive this object use  getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("Key") . Dont forget to make your pojo class or data class paraceable .

Answer (score 1):

replace this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, KayitDetay.class);

context.startActivity(intent);
```

with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, KayitDetay.class);
intent.putExtra("key",arrayList.get(position));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

after then on detail screen, fetch the key with the help of bundle

Comment: When i replace it with my code , it says , "Cannot resolve method 'putExtra(java.lang.String , com.example.cemal.login.RecyclerLayout)'

Comment: You need to do this Intent calling from activity rather then view holder.

Comment: And about the KEY thing , does it matter what i type there ? I mean , it is going to be the thing  i'll call on detail activity right ?

Comment: Just make it simple. Make one pojo class , set data in it and add that class in list of it. Click of cardView just pass that pojo class with position. Must be sure that pojo class should be implements with _Serializable_

Comment: But , RecyclerView doesn't have onClickListener. Is it ?

Comment: Just make an Interface or add callback for performing click. Only that is the correct way

Comment: @CemalÇelik _holder.itemVIew.setOnClickListener_ will be worked.

Comment: @CemalÇelik Yes, it will and implement `setOnClickListener` into your Activity, so that you can implement its method to perform click

Comment: Bad Answer..!! Intent in android don't override **putExtra()**to accept objects directly, the object either need to implement serializable or parcelable for this to work

Comment: It will automatically cast into either Serializable or Parcelable

Comment: @stutikasliwal  It will cast but you must be implement it with _serializable or parcelable_

Comment: @stutikasliwal if i will do starting new intent thing in activity , how can i get the position of it ?

Comment: @stutikasliwal No it won't cast automatically, as Piyush said, you need to implement those interfaces. Since automatic casting between non compatible types is not permitted in java

Comment: @CemalÇelik great!!, you have called `holder.itemVIew.setOnClickListener` in adapter or holder right? There you have position as an argument. Pass it over there as a parameter

Comment: @Piyush Yes!! you are right, but our AI is that much strong that it will guide about it. which is very beneficial for beginners

Comment: Sorry for the late response. @stutikasliwal Thanks for your effort. I've changed my on click to holder.itemview.setOnClickListener and passed position but , should i make arrayList.get(position) part Parcelable or Serializable. That is the what IDE recommends me. BTW , i am doing these things in my Adapter class.

Comment: @CemalÇelik Alright!! its ok, Go ahead and good luck. If you need any help then feel free to tag me anytime. And remember one thing making a model class will surely help you in that. because of its setter getter methods which you can use anytime any where just by passing

Comment: In this model , are all of my data returned from web service , passes to other activity ? I have 6 columns that returns from web service but i am just showing 2 of them in RecyclerView. In this situation , am i not passing just 2 that comes to recyclerview passes to other activity ?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse that is the reason why we make Pojo(model) classes, you can just use 2 or 3 as per your need and rest of them you can pass along. It is not necessary to use all the objects. From web service you can add 20 or more items and can use 2 only. There is no restrictions

Answer (score 0):

Create a listener Interface and let your Activity implement it.

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(Records record);
}
```

In your Activity:

```
public class MainActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(Records record) {
        // handle Item click data
        // pass record data to details activity here
    }
}
```

In your adapter:

```
  // declare this globally
  public OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener ;

  // ViewHolder
      @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(VideoHolder holder, int position) {
              holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            onItemClickListener .onItemClick(arrayList.get(position));
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your valuable answer. As i can see , you're implemented  activity from OnImageClickListener  but it is RecyclerView. Is that causes any problem ? I am asking bcuz i just don't get it sorry.

Comment: No. Make sure your pojo class should implement serializable interface to pass complete Record data to another activity.

Comment: I've added my POJO to question.